# How to download and upload xml files from ftp server in android?

Tags: android

Hi Everyone,
            I'm fresher to android, i have an code for downloading and uploading xml file from ftp server while establishing connection with ftp it is giving exception:- java.io.IOException: Unable to connect to server: Unable to retrieve file: 550, but this code well working in java but android it is throwing above exception please help me.

```
  **Xml File**  

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 

**Java Class**

imgBtnSyncRes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                File objfile=new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+ File.separator + "/index.xml");
                try {
                    objfile.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    download("ftp.qualityinaction.net/QIA/Questions/Airlines/","qualityinaction.net", "CpQual35","index.xml",objfile);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }


//File Downloading from ftp
     public void download( String strftpServer, String struser, String strpassword,
             String strfileName, File strdestination ) throws MalformedURLException,
             IOException
       {
          if (strftpServer != null && strfileName != null && strdestination != null)
          {
             StringBuffer strb = new StringBuffer( "ftp://" );
             // check for authentication else assume its anonymous access.
             if (struser != null && strpassword != null)
             {
                strb.append( struser );
                strb.append( ':' );
                strb.append( strpassword );
                strb.append( '@' );
             }
             strb.append( strftpServer );
             strb.append( '/' );
             strb.append( strfileName );
             /*
              * type ==> a=ASCII mode, i=image (binary) mode, d= file directory
              * listing
              */
             strb.append( ";type=i" );
             //OpenHttpConnection(strb.toString());

             BufferedInputStream bis = null;
             BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
             try
             {
                URL url = new URL(strb.toString());
                URLConnection urlc =(URLConnection) url.openConnection();
                //urlc.setDoOutput(true);
                //urlc.connect();

                //urlc.connect();

                bis = new BufferedInputStream( urlc.getInputStream() );
                bos = new BufferedOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(
                      strdestination.getName() ) );

                int i;
                while ((i = bis.read()) != -1)
                {
                   bos.write( i );
                }
             }
             finally
             {
                if (bis != null)
                   try
                   {
                      bis.close();
                   }
                   catch (IOException ioe)
                   {
                      ioe.printStackTrace();
                   }
                if (bos != null)
                   try
                   {
                      bos.close();
                   }
                   catch (IOException ioe)
                   {
                      ioe.printStackTrace();
                   }
             }
          }
          else
          {
             System.out.println( "Input not available" );
          }
       }

    //File uploading to FTP
     public void upload( String ftpServer, String user, String password,
             String fileName, File source ) throws MalformedURLException,
             IOException
       {
          if (ftpServer != null && fileName != null && source != null)
          {
             StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer( "http://" );
             // check for authentication else assume its anonymous access.
             if (user != null && password != null)
             {
                sb.append( user );
                sb.append( ':' );
                sb.append( password );
                sb.append( '@' );
             }
             sb.append( ftpServer );
             sb.append( '/' );
             sb.append( fileName );
             /*
              * type ==> a=ASCII mode, i=image (binary) mode, d= file directory
              * listing
              */
             sb.append( ";type=i" );

             BufferedInputStream bis = null;
             BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
             try
             {
                URL url = new URL( sb.toString() );
                URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();

                bos = new BufferedOutputStream( urlc.getOutputStream() );
                bis = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream( source ) );

                int i;
                // read byte by byte until end of stream
                while ((i = bis.read()) != -1)
                {
                   bos.write( i );
                }
             }
             finally
             {
                if (bis != null)
                   try
                   {
                      bis.close();
                   }
                   catch (IOException ioe)
                   {
                      ioe.printStackTrace();
                   }
                if (bos != null)
                   try
                   {
                      bos.close();
                   }
                   catch (IOException ioe)
                   {
                      ioe.printStackTrace();
                   }
             }
          }
          else
          {
             System.out.println( "Input not available." );
          }
       }
```

Comment: You need to include the exception log: add the logcat output, as it makes it MUCH easier to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: +1 to @Femi's comment. Also you do not want to make expensive operations (IO) inside an activity since it runs on the thread that renders the Views and it will make your app sluggish.

Comment: While we are at it may I recommend using Simple XML instead: http://simple.sourceforge.net/